# Windows service logic

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2005, windows-services

i need to send mails to the user once an incdient is reported.  the mail should be sent for 30 minutes after incident reported time and then 105 minutes after incident reporeted time and then 225 minutes after incident reported time.

I am using window service and C#, but i just need a condition for the serivce to execute the code.

here is my code.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
  timer1 = new Timer(1800000);
  timer1.Enabled = true;
  timer1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Timer1_Event);
}


public void Timer1_Event(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  if(datetime.now==incidentreportedtime+30mim)
  {
    //Send mail to user
  }
}
```

My question is incident can raise at any time and that time may not be eaual to the time at which service executes the code.

For example, incident raised time is at 12.45pm and the mail to be sent at 1.15pm. the serivce might have started at 12.50pm and again starts at 1.20pm which is not equal to 1.15pm. there can be few incidents with the same time as 1.20pm but not all the incidents can be considered to send mail.

Help me.

Comment: What is your question? It looks like a request for someone to write a windows service for you.

Comment: i did not get you what you are asking about. you should have asked me about the question i posted there. Please help me with your logic to do this task. i dont need code.

Comment: I'd like to file an incident.

Comment: Chaitanya... you are specifically asking to provide you with logic and code.... your requirement seems to be very clear... so this is not a question...

Comment: I need the logic. i can write the code.

Comment: @chaitanya "My question is incident can raise at any time and that time may not be eaual to the time at which service executes the code." - No, that is not a real question.

Comment: Yeah, I am sorry, i know i could not convey my question clearly. but i have checked my self before posting the question. my question is " suppose an incident raised at 10.00am and the mail need to be sent at 10.30am. if the window service started at 9.40 and again starts at 10.10 and again 10.40 and so on... and the 10.30am time (time at which to be mail sent) does not fall in the service running times. so how can i do this. i hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Timer1_Event(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
  if(DateTime.Now.Substract(incidentreportedtime).TotalMinutes == 30)
  {
    //Send mail to user
  }
}
```

And make sure the timer runs once each minute..

to send a mail google some thing like .net Send Mail my first hit: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/10/432854.aspx

Comment: `DateTime.Now.Substract(incidentreportedtime).TotalMinutes` is a bit more clear imho. otherwise +1. Just the answer I was typing when I got the dreaded "A new answer has been posted, press here to reload"

Comment: Thank you but its restircted (in my case, not progrmatically) to run the service for every minute. so is there any possibility to do this with out running the service for every minute.

Comment: if you log when you sent a mail last for each incident you can calculate how long ago it was last time...

Comment: Thank you. i feel you understood my problem better.